# iOS 3D indoor navigation application

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, 3d

what are the steps needed to create an indoor 3d navigation application. I have some auto cad files for a building and it would not be a problem to create a 3d model using 3dmax. Inertial sensors will be used for localization, bit After getting the model, how can I integrate it in iOS and create the visualization?

Comment: Do you know how to do ios openGL programming?

Comment: No, i will learn, or seek professional assistance if required.

Comment: Do you have any sensors other than the inertial ones?  If the user is sitting down and tilting his head or something, I can see it working -- but, purely inertial navigation good enough track you around a building for minutes at a time is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your complete requirements are i believe it sounds like you do require openGL programming in order to create that 3D environment. And for navigation, i would suggest using the GPS in order to specify where you are located as opposed to inertial sensors. Or maybe a Mix of both so as to reduce your errors. I am guessing you want to be able to locate yourself in a building where GPS and wifi or 3G signals are not available. Just making use of inertial sensors would definitely be error prone.